# What does "uncomfortable with taking a political stance" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> [If people in the classical world are uncomfortable with taking a political stance, they might at least worry about appearing to be stupid.](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/culture/2013/10/women-gays-and-classical-music.html)

What does this mean?

Comment: Is there anything in particular you find confusing about this sentence?  (For example, the overall structure?)

Comment: It seems to me (_I haven't still read the source yet_) that the sentence is kind of mocking for not taking any political stance and pushing the world to take political stance, **if necessary**. My conjecture is the sentence makes it clear the fact that the classical world has been turning a blind eye towards the politics always playing around them. Now they never took a stand politically, but this position of theirs is making themselves weak and "stupid" to the public and that they should leave this stand now and take politics into account of their business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"in the classical world" means people who are involved in classical music, in this case. "People in the programming world" would refer to people involved in programming.

"taking a political stance" means to have a political belief.

"they might", in this case, means "maybe they should" or just "they should". You could say "you might put a lid on your coffee cup" to somebody that does not have a lid on their coffee cup, but you think that they should. You can imagine some missing words, like "they might (if they were smart) at least worry...".

"at least" means "if nothing else" or "if you just do one thing, do this".

Another version of the sentence could be: "People who work in classical music should not want to appear stupid, even if they are not interested in politics."